# How to configure translate text extension on firebase to translate a text in a map field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I am trying to translate a text thats inside a map field.  [image]

This is how the collection is set up. I want to translate the "Text" field.

[image]

I tried "test.textDoc.*.text", but "dot notion" doesn't seem to work. I even tried "test/textDoc/{random}/text".

Answer (score 0):

For the [Translate Text](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/firestore-translate-text) extension to work, the text to translate has to be in a known, fixed field in your document. In our example, that'd be `ocnuwen.text`, but the `ocnuwen` cannot be variable.

Keep in mind that Firebase Extensions are open-source, so you can use the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-translate-text) of that extension as a template for your own - and tweak it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could you point me to a tutorial or a doc that shows how to do this? I have being searching, but I can't seem to find any. I am using firestore Web version 9 in my React app.

Comment: You mean, how to take the code that I linked and modify it? There's very little specific to Firebase in that process, it's pretty similar to forking any other repo.